# Filter multiple values using Python.get

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am using below code to filter the data of json list.

```
new_list = list()
for lot in json_ls:
    recs = lot.get('recipients')
    lot_recipients = [rec for rec in recs if rec.get("code") == "user1"]
    if lot_recipients:
        new_list.append({"lot_number": lot.get('lot_number'),
                         "recipients": lot_recipients})
```

It filter the data where code == "user1"

However I need to filter the data if code is either having "user1" or "error". All recipients who is having code is "user1" or "error" for each lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and you only need the two values (`user1` or `error`) you can change the line

```
lot_recipients = [rec for rec in recs if rec.get("code") == "user1"]
```

to

```
lot_recipients = [rec for rec in recs if rec.get("code") in ("user1", "error")]
```